# How to run Jasmine specs from Gulpfile.js when i need spy.js and mock-ajax.js file in jasmine specs

Tags: unit-testing, gulp, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, gulp-jasmine

My Folder Structure is as below:

```
Root
|- Scripts
    |- ViewScripts
        |- Feature_1
            |- feature_1.js
    |- Jasmine
        |- Helpers
            |- jasmine.js
            |- Spy.js
            |- mock-ajax.js
            |- jasmine-jquery.js
|- Tests
    |- Feature_1_Tests
        |- feature_1.tests.js
|- chutzpah.json
|- gulpfile.js
|- package.json
```

Content of **chutzpah.json** is :

```
{   "Framework": "jasmine",   "References": [
    { "Path": "Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" },
    { "Path": "Scripts/Jasmine/Helpers/jasmine.js" },
    { "Path": "Scripts/Jasmine/Helpers/jasmine-html.js" },
    { "Path": "Scripts/Jasmine/Helpers/boot.js" },
    { "Path": "Scripts/Jasmine/Helpers/mock-ajax.js" },
    { "Path": "Scripts/Jasmine/Helpers/Spy.js" },
    { "Path": "Scripts/Jasmine/Helpers/jasmine-jquery.js" }   ] }
```

Content of **gulpfile.js** is :

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');

gulp.task('tests', () => 
    gulp
        .src('Tests/**/*.tests.js')
        .pipe(jasmine())
);
```

Content of **package.json** file is :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp tests"
  },
  "author": "Jai Kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-jasmine": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

When i do **gulp tests** from **cmd** then :

1. All test cases failing.
2. I'm seeing following error for each test case -
   **ReferenceError**: **functionNameWhichIHaveSpyOn** is not defined
3. After all test cases ran and failed, message in the bottom of cmd is there **Error in plugin "gulp-jasmine"**

But when i'm running same test cases using chutzpah in Visual Studio Test Explorer all test cases passed.

Please help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance.